# IE 7 is Turning My Horizontal Nav Bar into a Double Line

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I am working on my site in Firefox 3.0.9 (and am very green with CSS) and it looks fair so far. However I have a floating horizontal nav bar at the top that looks like is stepping down. Here is what I attempted so far:

1) I have adjusted the margins, zeroed the padding and changed the width of the background image - all to no effect.

2) I tried to create a IE7 folder and point the browser their with a different stylesheet - no effect.

3) I tried to use IE7.js to solve the issue - no effect.

IE is driving me batty! Any thoughts? Here is my CSS & HTML (no laughing ;-) )

Thanks!

/*---my css---*/

```
#body       {
        margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
        text-align: center; 
        background: #450000 url(images/greenstrip.jpg) repeat-x right top;
        }

#maincontainer  {
        width: 720px;
        border-width: 8px;
        border-color: #fff;
        border-style: solid;
        position: absolute;
        margin-left: 50%;
        left: -360px;
        margin-right: auto;
        }


#box p      {
        position: absolute;
        color: #fffceb;
        width: 450px;
        margin-top: 275px;
        margin-left: 16px;
        background: #373635;
        font-size: medium;
        font-family: "arial rounded mt bold", "times roman";
        text-align: left;
        line-height: 1.5em;
        padding-left:7px;
        padding-right:7px;
        padding-bottom:7px;
        border-style:solid;
        border-color:#bec783;
        border-width: 3px;
        }



#lowerbox p {
        position: absolute;
        color: #fffceb;
        width: 450px;
        background: #373635;
        font-size: medium;
        font-family: "arial rounded mt bold", "times roman";
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 1.5em;
        padding-left:7px;
        padding-right:7px;
        padding-bottom:7px;
        border-style:solid;
        border-color:#bec783;
        border-width: 3px;
        width: 450px;
        margin-top: 433px;
        margin-left: 16px;
        }

#featured p {
        position: absolute;
        color: #000;
        width: 270px;
        margin-top: 825px;
        margin-left: 128px;
        background: none;
        font-size: small;
        font-family: "arial rounded mt bold", "times roman";
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 1.5em;
        }

#customize p    {
        position: absolute;
        color: #000;
        width: 270px;
        margin-top: 825px;
        margin-left: 420px;
        background: none;
        font-size: small;
        font-family: "arial rounded mt bold", "times roman";
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 1.5em;
        }


.name       {
        font-weight: bold;
        font-style: italic;
        color: #bec783;
        }

ul      {
        margin: 0px;
        width: 680px;
        line-height: 0em;
        list-style: none;
        font-size: medium;
        font-family: "arial rounded mt bold", "times roman";
        float: left;
        background: url(images/button.gif);
        }


ul a        {
        display: block;
        padding: 0 1.2em;
        line-height: 2.2em;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fff;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 6px;
        margin-right: 0;
        }


ul li       {
        float: left;
        width: auto;
        }


ul a:hover  {
        color:#f26214;
        }

ul a:visited    {
        text-decoration: none;
        }


#textpad ul     {
        position:absolute;
        width:100px;
        margin-top: 335px;
        margin-left: 481px;
        background: none;
        text-decoration: none;
        }


.promise a  {
        display: block;
        color:#000;
        line-height: 1em;
        font-size: 30px;
        font-family: "freestyle script";
        width:150px;
        }

.promise a:visited  {
            text-decoration: none;
            }

#fet a:link, #fet a:visited {
                text-decoration:none;
                color: #000;
                }

#fet a:hover    {
        color:#f26214;
        }



<!---HTML--->

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">


<head>
<title>Core 4 Innovative: Website Solutions For Your Small Business</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta name="keywords" content=" core 4,web,webpage developer,design,web designer, freelance,low cost" />
<meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />

<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.0(beta3)/IE7.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />

</head>


<body id="body">
<div id="maincontainer">
<table id="Table_01" width="720" height="961" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">


<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="http://www.core4innovative.com/home.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.core4innovative.com/about/about.html">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.core4innovative.com/process/our_process.html">Our Process</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.core4innovative.com/services/services.html">Our Services</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.core4innovative.com/contact/contactus.aspx">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="textpad">
<ul>
<li class="promise"><a href="#">Affordable Web Hosting Starting at $9.99 per month!<a></li>
</ul>


<div id="box">
<p><span class="name">Core 4 Innovative</span> puts your online success within reach. Using our affordable 
website solutions, unique development process and standardized
methods for design you can be sure to recieve a customized product that adds value to your business!</p>
</div>

<div id="lowerbox">
<p><span class="name">We Serve Every Major Industry:</span></br> 
Restuarants • Real Estate • Insurance • Entertainment • Apparel • Automotive • Energy • Professional Services</p>
</div>

<div id="featured">
<p><span id="fet"><a href="http://www.core4innovative.com/portfolio/portfolio.html" alt="our featured client">Our Featured Client</a></span></p>
</div>

<div id="customize">
<p>Customize Your website</p>
</div>

<tr>
<td colspan="3">
<img src="images/top.jpg" width="720" height="12" alt=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>

<img src="images/logo.jpg" width="258" height="137" alt=""></td>

<td colspan="2">
<img src="images/apple_graphic.jpg" width="462" height="137" alt=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="3">
<img src="images/topdivider.jpg" width="720" height="48" alt=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<img src="images/topdivider-06.jpg" width="502" height="3" alt=""></td>

<td rowspan="2">
<img src="images/notepad.jpg" width="218" height="305" alt=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<img src="images/getaquotebox.jpg" width="502" height="302" alt=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="3">
<img src="images/roundboxes.jpg" width="720" height="370" alt=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="3">
<img src="images/footer.jpg" width="720" height="88" alt=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<img src="images/spacer.gif" width="258" height="1" alt=""></td>
<td>
<img src="images/spacer.gif" width="244" height="1" alt=""></td>
<td>
<img src="images/spacer.gif" width="218" height="1" alt=""></td>
</tr>
</table>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Might want to add "css" & "html" tags to get this seen by more people.

Comment: ... and you may want to research 'short hand selectors' for more succinct code.

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten to put your nav in a `<td>` and a `<tr>`. Once you start a `<table>`, everything after that tag, that is not a "table tag" (such as `<th>` needs to be in a `<tr>`, and a `<td>`. For more information on this see: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

To fix this, simply put your ul in a `<tr>` and `<td>`

```
<tr><td>
<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="http://www.core4innovative.com/home.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.core4innovative.com/about/about.html">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.core4innovative.com/process/our_process.html">Our Process</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.core4innovative.com/services/services.html">Our Services</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.core4innovative.com/contact/contactus.aspx">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</td>
</tr>
```

Also, any other html elements on the page need to be in a `<tr>` or `<caption>`) and a `<td>` tag (such as your div's "box" and "lowerbox"; the divs need to be closed before you start another `td`).

If I were you, I would get rid of all of the table elements all together. If you really want to use a table for layout of your content, then use it only in the content area. You do not need to start your table with all your images until you get to the content area.

Also, to avoid future css headaches, always begin your css file with a css [reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/). This will help you on your way!

The css that you are using to style your nav is fine. For all the bad rap that IE get (totally deserved), the errors are sometimes due to coder negligence (ie you forget to close your tags). Most browsers are nice and ignore your negligence, but IE often does not clean up your missing tag mess.

I offer a simple page structure to place your code into.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <!-- your <ul> nav -->
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <!-- your table with images (if you really want to use a table! -->
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <!-- your footer info -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just as a side point, the <caption> element does not need to be in a <td> or <tr>. Nor do the <thead>, <tbody>, or <tfoot> elements. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, getting rid of the width: 680px in the ul fixes it... not sure what the specific IE bug is that's causing it, but that width seems to be being applied to the last item in the list rather than the list as a whole. Use a poor-man's firebug by putting a border in your ul li (border: solid 1px #f00;) style to see it.

Perhaps someone else can provide more detailed info into the why...